# How to prove there are an infinite number of squarefree numbers of the form $2^p-1$?

Tags: number-theory, open-problem

How to prove there are an infinite number of squarefree numbers of the form $2^p-1$, where $p$ is prime?

[It is conjectured that *all* numbers of the form $2^p-1$ are squarefree](http://staffwww.fullcoll.edu/dclahane/posters/gillumposter.pdf).  I've been having trouble proving that there are an infinite number of squarefree numbers of the form $2^p-1$; also I am unable to prove it for numbers of the form $2^n-1$ when the restriction on prime exponents is dropped.  I can see that there are an infinite number of primes which divide some number of the form $2^p-1$ (all primes dividing $2^p-1$ are larger than than $p$, so if $p$ is the largest known prime dividing any number of this form, there is an even larger prime dividing $2^p-1$).  Also I can prove the related statement that there are an infinite number of squarefree numbers of the form $n^2+1$ by overcounting the squareful values according to squares of primes of the form $4k+1$, and after some fiddling, bounding them below a constant fraction, but I can't figure out how to adapt this idea to the $2^p-1$ case.

Hints as well as full solutions are appreciated.

Comment: This might be very non-trivial.

Comment: If you start by _letting $p$ be a prime_, then there is exactly one number of the form $2^p-1$, and this number is either square-free or it isn't,

Comment: Did you know that it hasn't even been proved that there are an infinite number of *composites* of the form $2^p-1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson He might want to post this on mathoverflow to see what has been done on this.

Comment: Well, if you believe that there are infinitely many Mersenne primes, you automatically believe this fact. My guess would be that this is a hard fact.

Comment: Unfortunately [the problem seems to be open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime#Connection_with_Mersenne_and_Fermat_primes).  Incredibly, it is also unknown if there are an infinite number of non-Wieferich primes.

Comment: Wait a second, $2^0 - 1 = 0^2$ and $2^1 - 1 = 1^2$. Should $p>1$ be added to the question. Mhh, maybe it doesn't matter. You *are* dealing with infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an **open problem** (mentioned also in a comment) as conjectured by Schinzel.

An interesting consequence, due to Rotkiewicz, is that your open question - if true - would imply there are infinitely many primes $p$ for which $2^{p-1} \not\equiv 1$ (mod $p^2$).

This latter statement was shown by Silverman to be a consequence of the $abc$-conjecture, so it's "probably" true (perhaps someday Mochizuki's work will be verified or refuted...).

Thus, there is little hope of using Rotkiewicz's work to contradict the infinitude conjectured here.

I am re-tagging this as open, but you might find the citation below of interest.

**[Book](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDgQFjAC&url=http://library.worldtracker.org/Science/680%2520maths%2520books/Number%2520theory/My%2520Numbers,%2520My%2520Friends%2520-%2520Popular%2520Lectures%2520on%2520Number%2520Theory.pdf&ei=SEecUsbmF4fMsQSelYL4Ag&usg=AFQjCNG63r6wE7E8WC73jxwI1r5f7YIn3g&sig2=Di40sAvlFVQPMhaOGRf2iw&bvm=bv.57155469,d.cWc):** Ribenboim, P., Numbers, M., & Friends, M. (2000). Popular Lectures on Number Theory.

---

**Edit:** See also the MO post [**here**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150247/density-of-all-n-such-that-2n-1-is-square-free).